# SQL Server: how to generate serial number by dynamic SQL

Tags: sql-server

```
create procedure test 
    (@TABLE_NAME varchar(20))
as
    declare @lastval varchar(10)

    set @lastval = right('000000000' + convert(varchar(10),
                          (select IsNull(max(Serialno), 0) + 1 
                           from @TABLE_NAME)), 10)
    return @lastval
end
```

1. Now tell me how I could compose or form dynamic SQL with above SQL where I will pass table name to store procedure when call that stored procedure?
2. How to return `@lastval` value to its calling environment?
3. How to call stored procedure test from another stored procedure where I will store the return value ?

Guide me with sample code.

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? [`sp_executesql`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: There's a great book: [Dynamic SQL](https://www.apress.com/gp/book/9781484218105#otherversion=9781484218112) by Edward Pollack (Apress).

Comment: You could use sp_executesql to do that IF that needs to be an SP, however that looks like a very unnecessary procedure. Maybe instead you should tell what you are trying to do and why.

Comment: This approach will be prone to race conditions unless you lock the table. Instead, consider a separate table keyed by table name storing the last assigned value. That will allow you to calculate, update, and retrieve the next value in an atomic update statement and avoid dynamic SQL entirely.

Comment: Sounds like identity key might be in order too.

Comment: @dan would you please post a example what you are saying.

Comment: @DanGuzman would you please tell me why my approach will create race condition?

Comment: @KendoStarter, if you run the proc on 2 different connections at the same time, the same MAX value will be returned. Assuming each connection then attempts to insert the same value into the target table, one will succeed and the other fail with a duplicate key violation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Genearlly, it's best to use an `IDENTITY` or a `SEQUENCE` to assign serial numbers. A zero-padded string or other formatting requirements could be added to the table as a computed column based on the underlying serial integer or formatted in the app code. However, both `IDENTITY` and `SEQUENCE` may have gaps, such as due to rollbacks or SQL Server service restart.

In cases where an unbroken sequence of serial values is required by business, one can maintan the last assigned values in a table and assign values transactionally. Below is an example that returns the value using an `OUTPUT` parameter. Although the proc in your question uses the stored proc `RETURN` value for this purpose, that should only be used to indicate success or failure, not return data.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.TableSerialNumber(
      TableName sysname NOT NULL
        CONSTRAINT PK_SerialNumber PRIMARY KEY
    , SerialNumber int NOT NULL
    , FormatString nvarchar(20) NULL
);
GO
INSERT INTO dbo.TableSerialNumber VALUES('Invoice', 0, '0000000000');
INSERT INTO dbo.TableSerialNumber VALUES('PurchaseOrder', 0, '0000000000');
GO

CREATE PROC dbo.GetNextSerialNumberForTable
      @TableName sysname
    , @FormattedSerialNumber varchar(10) OUTPUT
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON;
DECLARE
      @SerialNumber int
    , @FormatString nvarchar(20);

UPDATE dbo.TableSerialNumber
SET
      @SerialNumber = SerialNumber += 1
    , @FormatString = FormatString
WHERE TableName = @TableName;
IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0
    RAISERROR('Table %s does not exist in dbo.TableSerialNumber', 16, 1, @TableName);
SET @FormattedSerialNumber = CAST(FORMAT(@SerialNumber, @FormatString) AS varchar(10));
GO

--example usage
CREATE PROC dbo.InsertInvoice
    @InvoiceData int
AS
SET XACT_ABORT ON;
DECLARE @InvoiceNumber varchar(10);
BEGIN TRY
    BEGIN TRAN;
    EXECUTE dbo.GetNextSerialNumberForTable
          @TableName = N'Invoice'
        , @FormattedSerialNumber = @InvoiceNumber OUTPUT;
    INSERT INTO dbo.Invoice (InvoiceID, InvoiceData)
        VALUES(@InvoiceNumber, @InvoiceData);
    SELECT @InvoiceNumber AS InvoiceNumber;
    COMMIT;
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0 ROLLBACK;
    THROW;
END CATCH;
GO
```

Comment: TableName can be the data type of your choosing. I used `sysname` (`nvarchar(128)`) because that's the data type SQL Server uses for table names.