# How to handle generate custom composite key from multiple request

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, linq-to-entities

I would like to generate costume unique invoiceno with help of two column Year and CompanyId in SQL Server (composite key (Year, CompanyId, Invoiceno)).

I can do with custom login to generate this unique key but how can handle if multiple request come at same to insert record.

My expectation records as below :

```
InvoiceId | Year            | CompanyId | InvoiceNo
1         | 2018            |      1    | IN0001
2         | 2018            |      1    | IN0002
3         | 2018            |      2    | IN0001
3         | 2018            |      3    | IN0001
4         | 2019            |      1    | IN0001
5         | 2019            |      1    | IN0002
6         | 2019            |      2    | IN0001
```

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Create a computed column. If you must have a sequence with no gaps, [extend this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51696848/sql-server-how-to-generate-serial-number-by-dynamic-sql) for your needs.

Comment: @DanGuzman Thanks for response! How can i ensure that will become unique value each user if number of user request to insert record at same time.

Comment: @AGH as far as I can tell: you can't! As liong as you don't ensure the uniqueness automatically (e.g. by identity column, sequence or whatever) there is no way to tell which column should receive which invoice number. Is your InvoiceId an identity column? then you could try to perform a Row_Number evaluation and calculate the InvoiceNo using this....

Comment: @AGH, if `InvoiceId` is assigned via IDENTITY or SEQUENCE, you won't have dups with the computed column. With the no gaps method in the referenced answer, each session will get a different value. You should still have a composite primary key or unique constraint on the `InvoiceNumber` regardless.

Comment: @Tyron78 Thanks for the response. Row_Number is good idea, will try and let you know.

Comment: @DanGuzman Thanks for suggestion, will try and let you know.

Comment: @Tyron78 I have done my work as your suggested by Row_Number. I’m grateful for your assistance.

Comment: @AGH glad I could help. :-) Unfortunately, Luk posted the according answer :-P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One can use ROW_NUMBER to get a number that can be used to form such InvoiceNo.

```
SELECT 
 InvoiceId, [Year], CompanyId, 
 'IN'+ RIGHT(
        CONCAT(
         REPLICATE('0',3), 
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [Year], CompanyId ORDER BY InvoiceId)
        ) ,4) AS InvoiceNo
FROM YourInvoiceTable
ORDER BY InvoiceId
```

Test on *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2012&fiddle=7a7056a9ef9c6019801118413aa07f09)*

Comment: I just come here to post my answer as suggested by Tyron78 in above comments but here you already :). Anyway I appreciate your answer.

Comment: @AGH Thanks. Btw, the SQL was written for MSSQL 2008.  On 2012 or later, you can replace that RIGHT & REPLICATE trick by a FORMAT to get a number with leading zero's. F.e. `select FORMAT(12, '0000')`